# How to remove middle part from URL - mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to rewrite this url "www.domain.com/index.php?route=custom/static/page" to "www.domain.com/page" in htaccess file, basically just want to take out index.php?route=custom/static/ from urls.

I don't know regex so I tried http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/, but it only generates

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

which doesnt remove 'custom/static' from URLs, I tried a few other examples as well but only removes index.php? and doesnt pass variable, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the concept of using mod-rewrite?

In your question you have mentioned to use mod-rewrite to redirect

> "www.domain.com/index.php?route=custom/static/page", 
>   Here `$_Get['route']="custom/static/page"`]  `$url_parameter=$_Get['route']`

to

> "www.domain.com/page" [here $_Get['route']="page"],

So now you can mannually add "custom/static/" to the obtained value of `$_Get['route'].` as `$url_parameter="custom/static"+$_Get['route'] //For PHP`

Using your mod_rewrite you can fulfill your demands,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

But if you need out of box solution using .htaccess then I suggest learning "rewrite-engine" instead of using generating tool